# ¿Cómo asignar un valor a un atributo/id/div?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Quiero asignar a un atributo `id` una imagen dependiendo del valor que tenga.

Si el valor=0, le asigno la imagen 0.gif
Si el valor=1, le asigno la imagen 1.gif
...
Si el valor=n, le asigno la imagen n.gif
Código HTML:

```
echo "<td onclick=\"cambiar_estado(this);\" width=\"06%\" id=\"".$row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']."\" data-estado=\"".$row['estado']."\">" ?>
<!-- Columna ESTADO del usuario. -->
<center>
<div id="cambiar_estado_imagen" class="cambiar_estado_imagen">
    <?php
        echo "<a data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#modalEstado\" style=\"cursor:pointer\">"; //cursor:pointer -> estilo de dedo/raton encima de un link/evento.
            echo "<img id=\"img-cambio\" src=\"/imagenes/".$row['estado'].".gif\">"; //Cada ID tiene su imagen establecida(0.gif, 1.gif, 2.gif) dependiendo del estado mediante: $row["estado"];
        echo "</a>"; 
    ?>
</div>
</center>


<?php 
  echo "</td>"; 

    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalEstado">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Cambio de estados - Ventana emergente.</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body" style="background-color:#66D6F8;">
                <p>
                   <center><b>¿Deseas cambiar el estado del usuario/ID?</b></center>
                </p>
                </div>     

                <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer" style="font-weight: bold;">
                <span style="float: left;">
                    <button type="button" id="boton_exit" align="center" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Exit</button>
                </span>

                <button type="button" id="boton_uno" class="boton-estado btn-default">Boton 1</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button type="button" id="boton_dos" class="boton-estado btn-default">Boton 2</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Código:

```
function cambiar_estado(row) {
    //Conseguimos el estado actual.
    var estado = $(row).attr('data-estado');
    //Mostramos por consola el estado actual.
    console.log("El estado inicial es: "+estado);
    var opcion1, opcion2, label1, label2;

    //Hacemos las diferentes comprobaciones de los estados y valores de los botones.
    if (estado == 0) {
        opcion1 = 1;
        label1 = "Activo";
        opcion2 = 2;
        label2 = "Baneado";
    }else if (estado == 1) {
        opcion1 = 0;
        label1 = "Inactivo";
        opcion2 = 2;
        label2 = "Baneado";
    }else if (estado == 2) {
        opcion1 = 0; 
        label1 = "Inactivo";
        opcion2 = 1;
        label2 = "Activo";
    }

    //Añadimos el atributo VALOR al ID asignado.
    $('#boton_uno').attr('estado', opcion1);
    $('#boton_dos').attr('estado', opcion2);

    //Añadimos el atributo HTML texto al ID asignado.
    $('#boton_uno').html(label1);
    $('#boton_dos').html(label2);

    //Guardamos en una variable los valores que tenga el elemento id boton_uno o boton_dos.
    var boton1 = document.querySelector("#boton_uno");
    var boton2 = document.querySelector("#boton_dos");

    //Cambiamos el color de fondo de los botones dependiendo de si su valor es: activo/inactivo/baneado.
    if (estado == 0) { //Si el estado es = 0 (invalido-rojo), boton1=activo-verde ||| boton2=baneado-naranja.
        boton1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        boton2.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    } else if (estado == 1) { //Si el estado es = 1 (valido-verde), boton1=invalido-rojo ||| boton2=baneado-naranja.
        boton1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        boton2.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    } else if (estado == 2) { //Si el estado es = 2 (baneado-naranja), boton1=inactivo-rojo ||| boton2=activo-verde.
        boton1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        boton2.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }



    //¿Qué ocurre cuando pulsemos un boton para cambiar el estado? ¡¡¡Cambiamos el estado y la imagen!!!
    $('.boton-estado').click(function(){
        var estado = $(this).attr('estado');
        //Volvemos a mostrar por consola su valor actual.
        if (estado == 0) {
            $('#img-cambio').attr('src', '../imagenes/0.gif');
        } else if (estado == 1) {
            $('#img-cambio').attr('src', '../imagenes/1.gif');
        } else if (estado == 2) {
            $('#img-cambio').attr('src', '../imagenes/2.gif');
        }
        console.log("El valor actual es: "+estado);
    });  
}
```

Mi problema: ¿por qué no cambia la imagen cuando hago click en el boton y le asigno a ese id/div su nueva imagen?

Comment: Que no me actualiza la imagen al elegir el valor mediante un click en el boton.

Comment: Estás modificando el atributo `src` para un elemento con `id` `img-cambio` pero no veo en tu código que la etiqueta `img` tenga ningun `id`

Comment: ¿En lugar del php podrías poner el html generado? Asi se puede hacer un jsfiddle y lo vemos funcionando para encontrar el problema más facilmente

Comment: En JsFiddle no se admite código PHP y mi formulario en HTML tiene código PHP. Si queréis os dejo el link pero va a ser lo mismo que aquí. https://jsfiddle.net/omaza1990/svn1ptsn/

Comment: Por eso te pido el HTML, todo código PHP se procesa y cuando sirve una página lo hace en HTML

Comment: OP, te pide el codigo de la pagina una vez cargada, no del codigo que tu escribes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Y si en vez de seleccionar el `div` en el que está la imagen, y cambiar la imagen `src`, no pones un `id` a la imagen y referencias desde ahí?

ej:

```
echo <img id="img-cambio" src=\"/imagenes/".$row['estado'].".gif\">";
```

```
if (estado == 0) {
        $('#img-cambio').attr('src', '../imagenes/0.gif');
```

Comment: Ya probé esa opción anteriormente pero no sé porque no me reconoce ninguna función ni método. Probé también con "val".

Comment: Hola @omaza1990. Simplemente por curiosidad, ¿al final cual era el problema?

Comment: Por lo visto la ruta exacta: $('#img-estado').attr('src', '../imagenes/0.gif');, añadi el ID a la imagen y su src propio, y luego en el ajax lo valoré pero debí tener algun error "no apreciable" en la línea de código. Actualicé la pregunta en otra pregunta formulada. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Le estás intentando asignar a un `div` tu imagen. Lo que tendrías que hacer es hacer referencia a la imagen en sí y añadir el atributo que quieres cambiar en la función `attr`:

```
$('#cambiar_estado_imagen img').attr('src', '../imagenes/0.gif');
```

o

```
$('#cambiar_estado_imagen > a > img').attr('src', '../imagenes/0.gif');
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48927/discussion-on-answer-by-error404-como-asignar-un-valor-a-un-atributo-id-div).

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar en `td` estas llamando a algo inexistente.

Ponle un `id` al `img` para un acceso mas facil

y luego de eso implemente este codigo.

```
$('#ID_DEL_BOTON').click(function(){
   var estado = $('#ID_DEL_BOTON').attr('estado');
   if(estado == 0){
       $('img').attr("src", "../imagenes/0.gif");
   }//Los demas...
});
```

Comment: Ya tengo un ID en el img pero tampoco me funciona...

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que `#cambiar_estado_image` sea un elemento , lo que te falta es:

```
$('#cambiar_estado_imagen > a > img').attr('src', '../imagenes/0.gif');
```

$.attr espera 2 parámetros, el atributo a cambiar, y el valor del atributo.

En caso de solo pasar uno, devolverá el valor de dicho atributo, siempre y cuando exista.

Comment: Me reconoce y me coge el valor del boton pero no me actualiza ese elemento. En la consola sí lo coge.

Comment: @omaza1990  quieres cambiar la foto del `boton` o el del elemento `#cambiar_estado_imagen`?

Comment: del elemento. Pulsando el boton deberia cambiarse la imagen del elemento

Comment: Sería conveniente poder echarle un vistazo a la estructura html.

Comment: ya está integrado.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, tienes que seguir la ruta de los elementos desde el elemento nodo seleccionado hasta el elemento al que quieres cambiar un atributo.

Comment: Nada... Aun no consegui.

Comment: Ya funciona gracias a todos. $('#img-estado').attr('src', '../imagenes/0.gif');

Comment: ¿Por qué me cambia sólo la fila1/id1 aunque seleccione la fila12/id12, o fila86/id86? Sólo cambia la primera,...

Comment: Posiblemente se deba a que el selector que usas para el elemento a cambiar no es único.

Comment: ¿y cómo podría hacerse único... alguna solución posible?

Comment: Debes añadir algún elemento que lo diferencie, o usar otro tipo de selector (o incluso varios selectores)  Hay muchas formas de hacerlo y todas son válidas, tendrás que evaluarlo tú mismo.

Comment: ¿por qué me sale el mismo ID da igual en cual fila pulse? Siempre me sale el primer ID de la tabla.